# DBeaver - Dynamic variable in PIVOT - column

Tags: oracle, pivot, dbeaver, dynamic-variables

PS: Thanks for your understanding, my English isn't very good. ;-)
I use DBeaver and when I run this sql :

```
@set deb_period = 202010
@set end_period = 202109
 
WITH tmp AS (
            --Permet de générer une liste de mois entre les deux bornes temporelles
            SELECT to_char(add_months(to_date(:deb_period, 'yyyymm'), level -1), 'yyyymm') mois
                FROM dual
                CONNECT BY LEVEL <= months_between(to_date(:end_period, 'yyyymm'), to_date(:deb_period, 'yyyymm')) + 1
            )
 
SELECT DISTINCT
    per.inss
    ,tmp.mois
    ,CASE fam.type
        WHEN 'MONO' THEN 'M'
        ELSE 'D'
    END AS typ_fam
FROM
    beneficiaries ben
    LEFT JOIN lumpsum_beneficiaries lum ON lum.actor_id = ben.actor_id
    INNER JOIN actors ac ON ac.actor_id = ben.actor_id
    INNER JOIN persons per ON per.person_id = ac.person_id
        AND per.inss IN (00000018043)
    INNER JOIN historical_family_situations his_fam ON his_fam.concerned_natural_person_id = ac.person_id
    INNER JOIN family_situations fam ON his_fam.historical_fam_situation_id = fam.historical_fam_situation_id
    INNER JOIN tmp ON 
        /*AND*/ TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(tmp.mois, 'yyyymm'), -1)),'yyyymmdd')) BETWEEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(fam.start_date,'yyyymmdd')) AND NVL(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(fam.end_date,'yyyymmdd')),99991231)
WHERE lum.actor_id IS NULL
ORDER BY 1,2 ASC 
;
```

I get this result:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iv1Ww.png)

What I want to do is rotate the data and keep the variable part of the period.
This is what I do with Oracle sdl developer :

```
column chaque_mois new_value str_in_statement
select listagg(''''||mois||'''',',') 
within group (order by mois) as chaque_mois
from (
                   --Permet de générer une liste de mois entre les deux bornes temporelles
                   SELECT to_char(add_months(to_date(202010, 'yyyymm'), level -1), 'yyyymm') mois
                      FROM dual
                      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= months_between(to_date(202109, 'yyyymm'), to_date(202010, 'yyyymm')) + 1
                   )
;
WITH tmp AS (
                   --Permet de générer une liste de mois entre les deux bornes temporelles
                   SELECT to_char(add_months(to_date(202010, 'yyyymm'), level -1), 'yyyymm') mois
                      FROM dual
                      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= months_between(to_date(202109, 'yyyymm'), to_date(202010, 'yyyymm')) + 1
                   )
SELECT *    
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT
   per.inss
   ,tmp.mois
   ,CASE fam.type
       WHEN 'MONO' THEN 'M'
       ELSE 'D'
   END AS typ_fam
FROM
   beneficiaries ben
   LEFT JOIN lumpsum_beneficiaries lum ON lum.actor_id = ben.actor_id
   INNER JOIN actors ac ON ac.actor_id = ben.actor_id
   INNER JOIN persons per ON per.person_id = ac.person_id
    AND per.inss IN (00000018043)
   INNER JOIN historical_family_situations his_fam ON his_fam.concerned_natural_person_id = ac.person_id
   INNER JOIN family_situations fam ON his_fam.historical_fam_situation_id = fam.historical_fam_situation_id
   INNER JOIN tmp ON 
       /*AND*/ TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(tmp.mois, 'yyyymm'), -1)),'yyyymmdd')) BETWEEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(fam.start_date,'yyyymmdd')) AND NVL(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(fam.end_date,'yyyymmdd')),99991231)
WHERE lum.actor_id IS NULL
ORDER BY 1,2 ASC 
) 
PIVOT
(
MAX(TYP_FAM)
--FOR MOIS IN ('202010', '202109')
FOR MOIS IN (&str_in_statement)
)
;
```

Which gives me the right result:
[Result Pivot with dynamic variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UdpN.png)

**My question**: I try to adapt this sql to DBeaver but I get an error ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement. I think DBeaver doesn't want too much Column. Can you confirm and if so, is there any other way to get the same result in DBeaver?